# Text detection on LCD(16x2) display via Tesseract OCR

Tags: ocr, tesseract

I need to detect the value from an energy meter shown in an LCD display.
Is it possible to detect the text from the below LCD display using Tesseract OCR.
Or is there any other algorithm for detecting it? Can anyone guide me with this issue.
[ENERGY METER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAZkI.jpg)

Comment: Can you take a screen capture or other type of photograph of the energy meter?  AFAIK Tesseract expects a TIFF input to kick things off.

Comment: I'm  unable to add a picture of it since my reputation is low. Therefore I'm adding a link for it https://www.slideshare.net/mobile/makersofindia/arduino-lcd-display